# Aplitude not logging the event written in "applicationWillTerminate" iOS

Tags: ios, swift, amplitude-analytics

I have installed amplitude in ios project. I am able to send events to amplitude. I am able to see the events in dashboard.

But i am not able to see the app close event in dashboard.

Pleas find attached code below.

```swift
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    Amplitude.instance()?.logEvent("APP_CLOSED")
}
```

Comment: Are you certain that delegate method is being called?

Comment: yes delegate is calling.

Comment: I suspect that Amplitude batches events and that the app is terminated before Amplitude gets around sending the event.

Comment: Indeed, like `uploadEvents` perhaps.

Comment: i tried setting event upload eventUploadThreshold : 2 but not working

Comment: tried upload events also but didnet work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the following apple documentation,
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate

> Your implementation of this method has approximately **five seconds** to perform any tasks and return. If the method does not return before time expires, the **system may kill** the process altogether.

I am guessing that the process of logging this particular event takes more than 5 seconds to execute and hence is forcefully terminated.

Comment: i hope this is the reason.